# JavaFX ComboBox readFromFile

Tags: javafx, combobox

In JavaFX is it at all possible to fill a ComboBox with items read from a file?  Basically, I have a list of all the street names in a country and I want to display them within my ComboBox as options. Thanks.

Edit:
Finally found some time to actually tackle however I got stuck when it came to loading the array into the combobox. Any help?

This is the method which reads from the file:

```
    private String ReadTownsAndCities(String[] choice){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String s;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;

    try{
        fr = new FileReader("TownsAndCities.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while((s = br.readLine()) !=null){
            list.add(s);
        }
        choice = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

        fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exc){
        System.out.println("Cannot open input file.");
    }catch(IOException exc){
        System.out.println("Error reading file");

    }
```

Now I need to load it into this combobox:

```
    //locality combo box
    localityCombo = new ComboBox<>();
    //localityCombo.getItems().addAll();

    grid.add(localityCombo, 1,11);
```

Comment: The answer to the question of course is ***YES***! (Assuming the file is not too large) Anything else you'd like to know?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what format does the file have. If it contains many lines and each line is a street name, i would read the file line by line with a WHILE-Loop and for each iteration create a new Item in your ComboBox.